# Converting JTextField to an int array with exceptions

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, exception, jtextfield

So I've been trying to figure this out but to no avail. I have to convert JTextField to an int array while having two exceptions, NumberFormatException, and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I was able to find a method to convert it, but it wont throw the NumberFormatException when I enter letters.

```
try {
    int j=0;
    String str = "" + numbersField.getText();
    char digit[] = str.toCharArray();
        for (int i=0; i<digit.length; i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(digit[i])) {
                array[j]=Character.getNumericValue(digit[i]);
                System.out.print(array[j] + " "); //Checking if it works
                ++j;
            }
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
        System.err.println("NumberFormatException: Array can only hold integers");

    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e1) {
                System.err.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array can only hold up to 10 elements");
    }
```

Personally, I believe it's not throwing the NumberFormatException because it converts JTextField to char, but I could be totally wrong. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I only included part of the program since it's kinda lengthy in my opinion. Array is initialized way before this. The ultimate goal of this portion of the program is to have the user input a limit of 10 numbers while throwing an exception if a letter is inputted or if it exceeds 10 numbers. This is my first time using exceptions so I'm still relatively new to it, so please excuse me for any mistakes I've done.

Comment: where do you initialize `array[]`?

Comment: How much digits do you want to read? maybe it would be better to read all text as one big number and then convert to array of digits? I think you'll never have `NumberFormatException` because you checking if every character is a digit

Comment: Of course it won't throw NFE -- your if block will prevent it from analyzing non-digit characters, and you never parse with a NumberFormatException throwing method.

Comment: You need to say your ultimate goal here. If you're trying to prevent the user from entering non-numeric input, I'd use a DocumentFilter.

Comment: You know of course that you're getting the unicode numeric value for the digit, not its parsed number representation.

Comment: Either a `DocumentFilter` as Hovercraft suggested, or alternatively a [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can check if whole text has only digits, then convert text to `int` and then put all digits to array.

Try an alternative:

```
String str = numbersField.getText();

try {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(str);

    int[] array = new int[str.lenght - 1];
    j = array.length - 1;
    while (value > 0) {
        array[j] = value % 10;
        value /= 10;
        --j;
    }

} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    System.out.println("Enter only digits!")
}
```

UPD: also you need to check if `value < 0` and show an error (if you don't accept minus sign) and use str.trim() before converting to int

Comment: Thanks! It throws NumberFormatException now but now when it throws the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at 10 elements, it should allow 10, and throw it after 11. I've tried messing around with what you gave but nothing. I'll continue to look into. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm well maybe this could help, maybe not the most efficient but does its job:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JTextFieldIntToArrayValidation extends JFrame {

    private int[] integerArray;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField tf;

    public JTextFieldIntToArrayValidation() {
        createAndShowUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JTextFieldIntToArrayValidation test = new JTextFieldIntToArrayValidation();
                test.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        setTitle("Converting JTextField to an int array with exceptions");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        addComponentsToPane();
        addListeners();
        pack();
        tf.grabFocus();
    }

    private void addComponentsToPane() {
        button = new JButton("Convert JTextfield to array");
        tf = new JTextField(10);
        getContentPane().add(tf, BorderLayout.EAST);
        getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.WEST);
    }

    private void addListeners() {
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                String tmp = tf.getText();
                char[] chars = tmp.toCharArray();
                integerArray = new int[chars.length];

                try {

                    if (integerArray.length > 10) {//if digits entered are greater then 10. This however only allows for single digits!!!
                        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Array cannot be larger then 10: " + integerArray.length);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length(); i++) {
                        if (!Character.isLetter(chars[i])) {//if its not a letter
                            integerArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(chars[i] + "");//stops java handling chars as ints
                        } else {//its a letter
                            throw new NumberFormatException("Only valid integers must be entered no letters: " + chars[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    printArray();
                } catch (NumberFormatException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getContentPane(), ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void printArray() {
        for (int i : integerArray) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was more then I was expecting but thanks! I was able to incorporate the actionPerformed section of your program into mine and it worked like a charm! I didn't know you could use exceptions like that, the professor never went over it. Thanks!